# Parse Error In angular js Formvalidation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formvalidation.io

Hi guys this I am new angular js i am applying formvalidation but getting error

```
<form  name="myForm" ng-controller='formCtrl'>
    {{message}}
    <div class="form-group">    
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name='propname'  ng-model='propname' placeholder="Property No. or Name *" required>
            <span ng-show="myForm.propname.$dirty && myForm.propname.$error.required">Required!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Flat No. (if applicable)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Street Name *">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Search Full Postcode *">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
    <span class="floatRight">* Required fields</span>
</form>
```

when i load the page it give the error in console

angular.min.js:117 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%26%26&p1=is%20not%20a%20validNaNdentifier&p2=18&p3=myForm.propname.%20%26%26%20myForm.propname..required&p4=%26%26%20myForm.propname..required
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:6:412
    at Object.throwError (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:227:427)
    at Object.identifier (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:226:149)
    at Object.primary (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:225:234)
    at Object.unary (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:223:411)
    at Object.multiplicative (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:223:157)
    at Object.additive (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:222:493)
    at Object.relational (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:222:328)
    at Object.equality (http://localhost/PT/assets/js/angular.min.js:222:153)

Comment: HM, it appears to be working? http://plnkr.co/edit/kbuNVyoqg5SaRx0sN3y3?p=preview

Comment: @uglycode yes its working fine in fiddle but not in my project

Comment: Try to re-create the error on plnkr.co and paste the link here.